# Installing Ruby version 2.2.3 on windows - get config.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am completely new to programming and am trying to install Ruby on Windows (64 bit). I get to the config.yml message and cannot set up a command to get past this to full set up.

I have been doing research online and find many people say ruby and Windows are not compatible.

Can anyone help advise/send a link that is a good workaround?

Thanks,

Comment: Ruby does run under windows, however historically it has been a less than pleasant experience since developing / deploying on windows has been pretty much irrelevant so very little effort was spent on compatibility. If you are just starting out I would recommend using something like cloud9 which gives you a unix virtual machine so that you can follow along with tutorials.

Comment: Your question is slightly vague, can you explain how you are trying to install ruby and possibly share screenshots and/or error messages you got while installing ruby. While developing ruby on windows used to be a painful experience, it's gotten a whole lot better.

Comment: A few more details needed as bjhaid mentions. I'm also interested in the directory names you've chosen, in addition to those items

Comment: We run Windows with Ruby for dev.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Ruby on Windows. Probably the easiest way to get started with Ruby on Windows is to use [Ruby Installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/). They support up to Ruby 2.2.3 at the moment.

If you are looking for an alternative workflow, you might consider running a Vagrant machine on Windows. This workflow is described [here](http://nick-aschenbach.github.io/blog/2016/01/24/running-ruby-on-windows-with-vagrant/).

The workflow involves using your native environment to launch a virtual machine that more closely matches the one typically used to deploy your code. You get the benefits of the windowing system tools (Sublime Text, RubyMine, Notepad++, etc) with the benefits of running specs and code in an environment closer to a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** run Ruby on Windows, *if* you have the correct dependencies/libraries installed.

---

The best way to do this (if new) is to download a pre-compiled version of Ruby, from [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org):

- [EXE installer](http://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/rubyinstaller-2.2.3-x64.exe)
- [ZIP file](http://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/ruby-2.2.3-x64-mingw32.7z)

Choose one of the above; they provide you the ability to put the `Ruby.exe` executable on your system, which (if installing with ZIP), needs to be added to your system `PATH` var.

--

I can explain more if required. If you want specific responses, you need to provide specific points (IE the full error message for `config.yml` etc)